# How to create avd with google api for Intel x86 atom image?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using android-API 15 for development of an app, 
The android image I am using is Intel's x86 atom.

I can create AVD image for the android emulator using standard API-15 but not with Google API, because avd manager does not show any any options for x86 atom image. It does for arm only but the Arm flavour of the Image runs very slow on my Intel machine,

Any ideas how can I set up the x86 atom image with Google API -15 ? rather than plain APi-15

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out,

Need to follow these steps,

- run arm based android image in emulator,
- pull out 2 google map files from /system/framework and /system/etc/permissions/
- turn off emulator,
- start emulator with x86 image (API-10 or 15 whichever version you used to pull from)
- push the two files we pulled earlier to same place,
- push mkfs.yaffs2.x86 thiscan be download from http://code.google.com/p/android-group- - korea/downloads/detail?name=mkfs.yaffs2.x86
- adb push mkfs.yaffs2.x86 /data
- adb shell
- cd /data
- chmod 777 mkfs.yaffs2.x86
- ./mkfs.yaffs2.x86 /system system.img
- exit
- turn off emulator
- replace new system.img with existing system.img
- run emulator with x86 image and it should now support google apis

Comment: Don't forget that you need to pull the system.img from /data and replace it with the one in android-sdk/system-images

Answer (score 1):

the answer given by Ahmed is technically correct, but I got a better overview of what I was doing, here: http://codebutler.com/2012/10/10/configuring-a-usable-android-emulator/

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to download the image directly using SDK manager. It is available for API >= 19

Answer (score 0):

The reply by @Ahmed is good, but there is a way to do this with less steps and without using mkyaffs2 and pulling the image (which takes forever). All methods I have seen, like this one, rely on creating this system image from within the guest Android system, which is very slow, and hard to automate. My method tricks QEMU to persist the changes to /system into the disk image, instead of throwing them away.

You can see the full method here: http://confcompass-tech.blogspot.nl/2013/07/google-apis-in-x86-android-emulator.html